# Golang / Gin-gonic : Force POST headers to JSON

Tags: json, curl, go, go-gin

I am using Gin-gonic to create an API. All requests whether thats a GET or a POST will be in JSON.

I have an API call which works fine but I **have** to add these headers through with the cURL `-H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json"` otherwise the POST does not work as expected.

I tried adding this function as middleware but although it changed the headers slightly it still does not work as expected

```
func CORSMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {

        c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization")

    }
}
```

Headers when it works (with added header in cURL):
`Accept: application/json`
`Content-type: application/json`

Header when it doesn't work (no header in cURL): `Accept: */*` `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Is there any way to force the headers rather than asking the user to supply them?

Comment: As I know method `Set(key, value)` just sets value for _existing_ key. Method `Add(key, value)` adds new pair key-value or appends value if key exists.

Comment: @AlexKroll not really. HTTP  header allow multiple values for one key, so `Add(key, value)` do append value to existing key.

Comment: @JiangYD and what I was wrong?

src/net/http/header.go

// Add adds the key, value pair to the header.
// It appends to any existing values associated with key.
func (h Header) Add(key, value string) {
 textproto.MIMEHeader(h).Add(key, value)
}

Comment: @AlexKroll yes my mistake. anyhow the question not relate to duplicate key.

Answer (score 1):

`Content-type` is a import HTTP header letting server decide how to parse the HTTP body.

*Is there any way to force the headers rather than asking the user to supply them?*

Hard to say Yes or No, it is depends on your 'user'. For curl, it can not guess the HTTP body format and set Content-Type to 'applicatoin/json' automatically, so you need specify Content-Type. For others like jQuery, programmer can set the `dataType` in post `jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )` [link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)